# Solve for the coefficients of a quadratic surface given certain initial conditions.

Tags: calculus

Here is a problem on my homework.  I have been able to work through part of it but i have hit a bump in the road:

Let $L$ be the line determined by the equations $y = 6,~x = 10 z$. If we rotate $L$ around the x-axis, we get a surface whose equation is  $A x^2+B y^2+C z^2 = 1$.  Solve for the coefficients $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Hint: Pick a point on the line and rotate it around the x-axis...you will get a circle. Think about how the radius of that circle changes as the point changes.

$B$ is fairly easy to solve for.  If i plug in $x=0$, then $z=0$ as well, and you can easily plug in $y=6$ and get $B=1/36$.

After that I don't know where to go.  I can plug in a value for $x$ and get the relationship between $A$ and $C$ to be $C=-100A$.

How can I finish solving for these coefficients?  I believe that taking the Hint into account, making the circles, then the radius of the circle "slice" would be the value of C.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually i think i've just realize that since we are rotating all the way around the x axis, then the radius of the circle would be $y=6$ for $x=0$,  and then it would increase from there based on the value of C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

First analyze the curve at the point $(0,4,0)$.  When you take that point and rotate it around the x-axis, you get a circle of radius $y$, which is 6.

This circle of $radius=6$ is entirely in the $yz$ plane.  You can analyze it without the $x$ component for a minute.  The equation of circle will then be $y^2+z^2=6^2$ at $x=0$.

To get this to be in the same form as the equation given, you  must divide both sides by 36.  Thus the coefficients $B$ and $C$ will be equal to $1/36$. The resulting equation is: $(1/36)y^2+(1/36)z^2=1$.

Now choose another value for $x$ to obtain the value of $A$. Using $z=1$ and $x=10$ you get the following:
$$A(10)^2+(1/36)(6)^2+(1/36)(1)^2=1$$
Simplify that to $100A=-(1/36)$

Then $A = -1/(3600)$.

Thus the solution is $(-1/3600)x^2+(1/36)y^2+(1/35)z^2=1$.